# sites down but server up, what to do?

Tags: apache, debian

I could ping my websites but I got a 404 going there.
My server was running normally, no new mail for root.

- Is there a service to alert you when your websites are down ?
- What do you usually do to understand why it's down?

I took a look at the apache2/error.log and saw that it couldn't access one of the website I had deleted a few hours ago. I just did a a2dissite and restarted and it was fixed, I could access my websites.

I either got lucky or I postponed a problem. Any idea what I should do next to make sure everything is alright? (I'm on debian by the way)

Comment: not enough information to diagnose. Also, this is off-topic to Server Fault.

Comment: [1] http://serverfault.com/questions/73717/how-can-i-get-alerts-when-my-site-is-down [2] read the server logs

Comment: I don't want you to diagnose @Raptor, I want to know how I can diagnose.